# Branch.io initSessionWithLaunchOptions round tripping

Tags: branch.io

In AppDelegate and [branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions ...] - will there be any round tripping to branch.io backend(https://xxx.app.link/xxxx) when just opening the app not from a link?

Thanks in advance(Alex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(from the Branch.io team)*

Great question. The `initSessionWithLaunchOptions` method will be called **every time** your app launches, whether or not the open happened as a result of the user clicking a Branch link.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, just to be even more precise - the code block/closure(andRegisterDeepLinkHandler) is always called and therefore there is always a call to branch.io backend(https://xxx.app.link/xxxx)?

Comment: @AlexBauer What is the reason for this though? In what case would we want `initSessionWithLaunchOptions` to be called when a branch link hasn't been clicked?

Comment: @ShivamBhalla in every case — there is no way to know whether a Branch link has been opened until AFTER that call returns, because that's where the other half of the detection takes place. It's also used for your install/open analytics.